# Initialize object in C# with () or without

Tags: c#

What is the difference between initializing an object in these two ways:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
{
    Id = 1,
    Color = green
}
```

VS.

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject
{
    Id = 1,
    Color = green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, they compile to the same code.

Answer (score -1):

There's no difference - the parentheses in the first example are optional. Hope that helps.